# Holding a moving threshold in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, global-variables

I have a an app that allows voting on articles. The request is that the top twenty articles based on a moderately complicated voting scheme be flagged as "trending." Simple enough so far. Next request is that non-trending articles be given some indication of how close they are to becoming trending.

I can pull the 20th article and get its score and compare it to the viewed article each and every time someone views the record (and indeed, my naive implementation does just that) but I'm concerned for performance reasons. I'd like to cache that value and only re-query for the "Trending Threshold" when a record would break into the trending section which is much less common than reading and displaying this indicator will be.

Determining when to bust this cache is fairly straightforward. However, it seems over-kill to install something like Memchache or Redis to store this one number. Is there a simpler way to store this threshold and make it available to each request as it begins processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your answer is rather broad, I hope you don't mind me providing an answer equally so:

---

**Redis**

I was going to suggest using [`Redis`](http://redis.io) for this - I like to call it RAM for your app

Your main concern is performance. Therefore, your goal is to remove any "resource intensive" parts of your back-end, which is where asynchronicity comes in

I would set up a Redis instance (which will store two sets of data -- your list of "trending" votes; and your app's activity). You can then use something like [`public_activity`](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity) to send updates to Redis regarding a post's interactivity (views / votes)

This will give you a "live" stream of all the activity with different parts of the app. You'll then be able to run a rake task (I'm not sure how), which will continually evaluate this data & amend your app's `Trending` cache

This will split the load between your app `front-end` and `back-end` processes, freeing up resources

If you want me to write some code, please let me know!

Comment: I like this approach in a lot of ways. I'll give you some more context... All my articles are currently indexed in an ElasticSearch instance for a number of features. I have a numeric score that is based on each vote. Not all votes are equal, so indexing by a numeric score seemed to work well. If I have that trending threshold (the score of the 20th ranked article) then any time a vote comes in that would kick that article's score above the threshhold, I need to re-evaluate the trending list and the threshold. If I stored all 20, it would be trivial to grab the last one and get the threshold.